# Кількість імовірних складів в українській

Tags: фонетика

Мене надихнули такі питання: [*Source of syllable statistics of languages?*](//linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/33703/19599), [*How languages compare with the number of different syllables from all words?*](//linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36906/19599) і не лише.

Де щодо української, на жаль, нічого не сказано. Тож… чи є якась наукова робота на цю цематіку чи спроби обчислїння? Можна лише зазначити, що українська абетка не подібна до японської чи хінської, що дозволяють вже обраховати на місцї [з можливими декотрими поправками], то питання вже радше лежить на фонетіцї: які сполуки звуків можливі [тобто питомі для української в тий чи гинший спосіб].

Для порівняння, в тих питаннях згадані такі мови, що відносно схожі за структурою до української: анґлійська — 6949 / 15 тис., нїмецька — 5100, сербська — 3831…